# iteratively creating graphs

Tags: linux, unix, shell, scripting

I have a bunch of files containing x and y coordinates, representing time and value (space-separated, but can  be amended)

For example, in each file I will have this sort of points:

```
 15:06:59  0.0140
 15:07:00  0.0142
    ...etc....
```

I want to create a word file (or some equivalent) to show all these graphs.

Currently, I am using Excel. It pretty daunting task, as I have to plug paste numbers in two rows for each graph, and I have many of them, both graphs and points

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a TEX file and then compile it to the PDF?

Great example of creating line plots in TEX here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-plot-example/

Beside TIKZ there is also second package that allows you to create graphs programmatically: the [PGF plots](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgfplots.html)

Answer (score 0):

The word "iteratively" in the question title makes me think that you want to have a look at [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/).

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before, my solution was to write a C program that wrote all of these values into a [CSV file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Then simply use a CSV to .xls file converter.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the gnuplot program. This will allow you to produce charts using scripts and save them as images. It's pretty good and aimed specifically at producing charts.

alternatively you could try the R package - this is a full statistical analysis package and will produce lovely charts but it's got a substantially steeper learning curve than gnuplot